# In Joomla, I want clean URL

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

Here is my siteURL http://www.ebiztrait.com/CupidsElite/

I want to create internal pages for this site, with clean URL but as a content I want the same content as it is right now in home page.

So I just want to duplicate home page in siteURL/Success-Stories

Page should have clean URL like this siteURL/Success-Stories
 my main condition is I dont want to add anything in .htaccess.

I appreciate if anybody can help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to *add* anything in .htaccess you just need to enable it by..

Comment: Hi Scorpion,can you explain it little more? I dont understand by????

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs_on_Apache

Answer (score 0):

Logically It is not possible without touching .htaccess or server side configuration.
When you write the URL your server is definitely going to look for the index.php file in the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

1. login in joomla admin
2. goto global configration
3. SEF URL set to Yes
4. then finally save. and check.

Now, you can convert htaccess.txt file to .htaccess

then again check you site to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

For your request is inevitable that you might edit .HTAccess

just add the following  entry

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```